# Do the supremum and infimum always exist for convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

If $\{x_n\}$ is a real sequence converging to $x \in \mathbb{R}$, do 
$\displaystyle \sup_n{x_n}$ and $\displaystyle\inf_n{x_n}$ exist?

I think yes as, choosing $\epsilon = 1$ we have for some $K\in\mathbb{N}$

$|x_m - x| < 1$  ,  $\forall m > K$.

Then setting

$M = \max{(1, |x_i - x| ; i =1,...,K})$ we have $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$-M \leq x_n -x \leq M .$$

So $x_n \leq M + x$,  $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, so the sequence has an upper bound hence the supremum exists. Similarly so does the infimum.
Is this reasoning correct and is the claim right?  Is this also true for any bounded sequence, i.e. $\{x_n\}$ is totally contained in some open ball with radius $r\in\mathbb{R}$.  Will this be true for any cauchy sequence as well?

Is this also true for any (real)metric space and in particular function spaces, 
with real functions converging pointwise and or uniformly, as of course the above argument
is useless with other metrics. In general topologies if there is a linear or partial order also defined on it is there any relationship between converging nets and existence of supremums?  Would appreciate any feedback, Thanks in advance

I would appreciate any input, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If the sequence $(x_n)$ converges, the set $\{x_n\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded and every bounded subset of the real line has (finite) supremum and infimum.

I do not know how supremum and infimum are defined on more general spaces, say $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks, but was my reasoning above right, by bounded do you mean the $diam(\{x_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\})<\infty$ or that $(x_n)$ is bounded above and below. Take it that these two things are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, either way. Or that the set is included in some ball with finite radius.